# How to use expect or readlines if output is dynamic

Tags: pexpect

I am trying to log into a box and then want to check if log in successful or not. If it's success, console is printing "connected with "

In this case, if SSID is dynamic how can I use expect or readline? or is there any other way?

Comment: [The very first code example in the docs shows that `.expect()` method accepts regular expressions](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html). What do you want to happen if `"connected with"` is NOT printed?

Comment: session.expect('*SSID*')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1416, in expect
    compiled_pattern_list = self.compile_pattern_list(pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1328, in compile_pattern_list
    compiled_pattern_list.append(re.compile(p, compile_flags))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Comment: Don't put the necessary info in comments, [edit] your question and put the traceback there with proper formatting.